# Reload the Tab on clicking Again

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, reload

I have a `UITabBarController` With the 5 Tabs and I want When I click on the `Tab 2`and make changes on that by changing the options on that Tab and then move to Next Tab say `Tab3` and I want when again I come back to `Tab 2` the data should be reload of that.

Means `Tab 2(make changes)--> Tab 1 --> Tab 2(it should reload ,it should not display me the changes)`

How to reload that tab..

i was using the below code but does not works..the changes are remain same..

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: is `viewWillAppear` method called of Tab 2's first view controller ?

Comment: Implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method and reset the viewcontroller to be shown there. You can check the example mentioned here http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-taps-on-uitabbarcontroller-and-determining-class-type.html

Comment: ya but in `didSelectViewController` what should be the method to reset the view controller??

Comment: @Christien: When you click on tab 2 then it should display any of your views,right ? for that view, is `viewWillAppear` called ?

Comment: @Maulik no In viewWillAppear there no method to reload again Tab 2 (from starting) ..and wat should be that

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of doing that:

- in controller's viewWillApear: write your reload code. But it leads to reload everytime when view apears
- implement UITabBarControllerDelegate, do reload in shouldSelectViewController/didSelectViewController method.

Comment: is there any reload inbuilt method to call tab bar ?? or do i need to create something
?

Comment: @Christien what kind of data do you want reload ?

Comment: Like Nsdate (in simple)..it gives the same date when i come back ...I want it to reload ...

Comment: @Christien it seems you need to reload when controller's view will apear. There is no such inbuilt reload method.